# Why should I create a json to save a document from Mongoose + MongoDB + Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider, Mongoose schema:

```
var schema_obj = new Schema({
    field1: String,
    field2: String, .........
});
```

JSON document, like:

```
var json_obj = {
field1: 'value', 
field2 : 'val2', 
............
};
```

For saving I call method, like

```
var Model_obj = mongoose.model('model_name', schema_object);
var document_obj = new Model_obj(json_obj);
document_obj.save(function(err,data){/*some logic after save*/});
```

Now my question is: Why should I create a **json_obj**. 
When I already have a schema object in my hand, which already has all the fields (field1, field2). If I just want to give values for those fields why should I create json by writing all the field name again?

If I have *n* number of fields this becomes a overhead to write all fields again. Is there any way to avoid this overhead?

Something like I get a empty JSON object out of my defined mongoose schema, then just proceed by assigning only values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of API are you looking for? You can set properties on a model instance and `save` it. But I'm not sure if I understand why

```
var thing = new Thing();
thing.name = "The Name";
thing.priceInCents = 1999;
thing.numAvailable = 10;
thing.save();
```

is easier than

```
var thing = new Thing({name: 'The name', priceInCents: 1999, numAvailable: 10});
thing.save();
```

In a web app, this becomes something like

```
app.post('/things', function(req, res) {
  var thing = new Thing(req.body.thing);
  thing.save(function() { ... });
});
```

Comment: We cannot Set any properties on model object but we can on the document object. The code is right here.. Thanks for help..

Comment: I'm not positive what your last statement means, but I'm going by [this example in Mongoose's readme](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose#accessing-a-model). (In fact [Model inherits from Document](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/30c0f2f6f795140ff9b80ef72e41904329d5e5bd/lib/model.js#L34).)

Comment: I mean Thing (in caps T) is model object. May be I have got confused with this statement in http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html "each document will be a kitten with properties and behaviors as declared in our schema.".. Anyway thanks for the quick support..

Answer (score 1):

### The following is the best solution I have found so far

```
var sch_obj = new mongoose.Schema({
 "_id ": String,
 "field1": String,
 "field2": String
}, { collection: 'collection_name'});

var Mod_obj = mongoose.model('collection_name', sch_obj);

var json_obj = new Mod_obj({
"_id ": 'Strin', /*This is the only field which cannot be assigned later*/
}); 

//json_obj._id = 'some value'; /*THIS CANNOT BE DONE*/
json_obj.field1 = 'value1';
json_obj.field2 = 'value2';
json_obj.save(function (err, data) { console.log(data); });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES6, the spread operator might come in handy for this purpose. considering that you have your mongoose model defined and you are getting your field values from req.body. you can create a new object for that model by simply writing it like this:

```
const Thing = mongoose.model('collection_name', sch_obj); 
const json_obj = new Thing({ ...req.body });
json_obj.save()
.then(savedThing => {
    //DO things with your saved object.
})
.catch(error => {
   //Handle error in saving the object
})
```